# Loading image for heavy data process not showing up by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a `loading` image before heavy data process and remove it after done, so I wrote this code:

```
$("a#myId").click(function(){
    $(this).append('<img src="loading.gif" />');
    ...
    ... doning some heavy data process (that take more that 5 seconds) here ...
    ...
    $("img[src='loading.gif']").remove();
});
```

But the loading does not show! (when I leave `$(this).append('<img src="loading.gif" />');` and remove next lines, loading image display correctly)

Comment: what kind of data processing are you doing?

Comment: the best way is to add a "loading" class to your "a" element and remove it...

Comment: thanks silly, your simple way solve my problem.  it seems that add/remove element to/from DOM, need more longer time and cpu in compare with add/remove class.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this and it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/Z3MXJ/

```
<a id="myId" href="#">Click me</a>
<div id="target"></div>
<script>
$("#myId").click(function(){
    $('#target').append('<img src="http://www.consafelogistics.com/gfx_portal/loading.gif" />');

    var url = 'http://onerahi.cabu.school.nz/files/2012/09/goes-12-firstimage-large081701.jpg',
        img = $('<img>');
        img.hide();
        img.bind('load', function(){$(this).fadeIn();
            $("img[src$='loading.gif']").hide();
        });
        $('body div#target').append(img);
        img.attr('src',url);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deferred object

```
function processData( ) { ... }

$("a#myId").click(function(){

    $(this).append('<img src="loading.gif" />');
    $.when( processData ).then( function( ) { 
        $("img[src='loading.gif']").remove();
    });

});
```